# How to append a byte to a string in Java?

Tags: java, string, hex, byte

I have this operation I need to perform where I need to append a byte such as 0x10 to some String in Java. I was wondering how I could go about doing this?

For example:

```
String someString = "HELLO WORLD";
byte someByte = 0x10;
```

In this example, how would I go about appending someByte to someString?

The reason why I am asking this question is because the application I am developing is supposed to send commands to some server. The server is able to accept commands (base64 encoded), decode the command, and parse out these bytes that are not necessarily compatible with any sort of ASCII encoding standard for performing some special function.

Comment: A byte is not a character. What do you want the string to start and end as, and given what "byte" input?

Comment: 0x10 is not a displayable character in any ASCII compatible encoding. Why would you want a Data Link Escape in your string?

Comment: We know the variables, we have a hard time comprehending the desired output. What do you want to get? `"HELLO WORLD 0x10"`?

Comment: It sounds as he wants to append the name of the byte variable to the string, in this case "someByte" ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to concatenate the actual value of a `byte` to a `String` use the `Byte` wrapper and its `toString()` method, like this:

```
String someString = "STRING";
byte someByte = 0x10;
someString += Byte.toString(someByte);
```

Answer (score 4):

If you want to have the String representation of the byte as ascii char then try this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String a = "bla";

    byte x = 0x21; // Ascii code for '!'

    a += (char)x;

    System.out.println(a); // Will print out 'bla!'
}
```

If you want to convert the byte value into it's hex representation as String then take a look at [Integer.toHexString](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#toHexString%28int%29)

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to extend a String literal, then use this one:

```
System.out.println("Hello World\u0010");
```

otherwise:

```
String s1 = "Hello World";
String s2 = s1 + '\u0010';
```

And no - character are not bytes and vice versa. But here the approximation is close enough :-)